# Question about Cauchy Sequence proof for $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I was looking through a proof that the sum of $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2} =  1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}...$$ is convergent. I know there are probably other ways to prove this, but because I'm learning about functional analysis I want to prove it by first proving that this sequence is Cauchy.

The proof goes as follows. Consider any $\epsilon>0$, I can find you an $N$ in the sequence that is sufficiently large enough such that $\frac{1}{n}>\sqrt\frac{\epsilon}{2 }$ and $\frac{1}{m}>\sqrt\frac{\epsilon}{2 }$, where $n$ and $m$ are defined as greater than $N$. Thus:

$$|\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{m^2}|<\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{m^2}<\epsilon$$

Then the sequence is Cauchy.

But then I thought about the sequence: $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i} = \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} + \cdots.$$ If I just modify the proof a bit such that I let $\frac{1}{n}>\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and likewise for $m$, then won't it prove that this sequence is Cauchy as well? But this sequence is obviously not Cauchy. What's wrong with applying the above proof to this series?

Comment: You've show that $(a_n)$ is Cauchy, not that $\sum_{n=1}^m a_n$ is Cauchy (as partial sums)

Comment: You are confusing the sequence that you sum (say $a_n$) with the sum of the sequence ($S_N = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n$)

Comment: Thanks! Now that you've mentioned it, everything seems clearer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sum_{k = n+1}^m \frac{1}{k^2} < \sum_{k = n+1}^m \frac{1}{k(k-1)} = \sum_{k = n+1}^m \left(\frac{1}{k-1}- \frac{1}{k}\right) = \ldots$$

Comment: Sorry but did you read the question and what the OP is really asking?

Comment: @Did: I always appreciate your efforts to maintain high standards here. In this case, the comments seemed to have clarified the distinction between sequence of terms and sequence of partial sums -- based on the OP's acknowledgement. The question both in title and first paragraph seems to be how to prove series convegence through the Cauchy criterion -- hence, the hint.

Comment: Thanks all for your helpful answers. Yes, even though the comments clarified my doubts, the logical next step was how to prove the sequence convergence by showing that the sum of the sequence was Cauchy. And the answer did point me in the right direction. Any math is good math, so thank you to all those who are willing to help!

Comment: @YipJungHon: You're welcome and thanks for letting me know that this helped.